# Text on predefined line

Tags: c#, algorithm, graphics, gdi+

I have a broken line (`PointF[]`), some `string` and `Graphics` object. Now I want to draw this string on my line.

Here's an example:
[image]

Are there any algorithms to do that in the easiest way?

**[edit]**
Ok, I have tried @endofzero's code and modified it a little. Here's the whole solution (with angle and distance calculations):

```
private static void DrawBrokenString(Graphics g, IList<PointF> line, string text, Font font)
{
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);

    for (int index = 0; index < line.Count - 1; index++)
    {
        float distance = GetDistance(line[index], line[index + 1]);

        if (text.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int cIndex = text.Length; cIndex >= 0; cIndex--)
            {
                SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString(text.Substring(0, cIndex).Trim(), font);
                if (textSize.Width <= distance)
                {
                    float rotation = GetAngle(line[index], line[index + 1]);

                    g.TranslateTransform(line[index].X, line[index].Y);
                    g.RotateTransform(rotation);

                    if (index != line.Count - 2)
                    {
                        g.DrawString(text.Substring(0, cIndex).Trim(), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
                                 new PointF(0, -textSize.Height));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        g.DrawString(text.Trim(), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
                                 new PointF(0, -textSize.Height));
                    }

                    g.RotateTransform(-rotation);
                    g.TranslateTransform(-line[index].X, -line[index].Y);

                    text = text.Remove(0, cIndex);
                    break;
                }
            }    
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

        g.DrawLine(pen, line[index].X, line[index].Y, line[index + 1].X, line[index + 1].Y);
    }
}

private static float GetDistance(PointF p1, PointF p2)
{
    return (float) Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p2.X - p1.X, 2) + Math.Pow(p2.Y - p1.Y, 2));
}

private static float GetAngle(PointF p1, PointF p2)
{
    float c = (float) Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p2.X - p1.X, 2) + Math.Pow(p2.Y - p1.Y, 2));

    if (c == 0)
        return 0;

    if (p1.X > p2.X)
        return (float) (Math.Asin((p1.Y - p2.Y)/c)*180/Math.PI - 180);

    return (float) (Math.Asin((p2.Y - p1.Y)/c)*180/Math.PI);
}
```

Now I need the only one thing to finish my problem. I don't want the strings to overlap each other. Any ideas? Ahhh, and when we can't draw a string on the path (because of too much amount of breaks it should be drawn above the line (middle top).

Here's the example of unwanted overlapping:
[image]

Comment: Was the input string "Some text on the line" or ["Some Text", "on the line"]?

Comment: I get whole string, so "Some text on the line":S I have to split it myself

Comment: You can draw rotated text using DrawString after a proper RotateTransform (more on it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z3f662(v=vs.100).aspx) and you can see the width of a string using the MeasureString method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring(v=vs.100).aspx). This can help you splitting the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how to draw text following a broken line.

```
    private static void DrawBrokenLine(PointF[] line, string text, Graphics g, Font font)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < line.Length - 1; index++)
        {
            float distance = distanceBetween(line[index], line[index + 1]);

            if (text.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int cIndex = text.Length; cIndex >= 0; cIndex--)
                {
                    SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString(text.Substring(0, cIndex).Trim(), font);
                    if (textSize.Width <= distance)
                    {
                        float rotation = angleBetween(line[index], line[index + 1]);

                        g.TranslateTransform(line[index].X, line[index].Y);
                        g.RotateTransform(rotation);

                        g.DrawString(text.Substring(0, cIndex).Trim(), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
                            new PointF(0, -textSize.Height));

                        g.RotateTransform(-rotation);
                        g.TranslateTransform(-line[index].X, -line[index].Y);

                        text = text.Remove(0, cIndex);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
```

If you want it to only break at spaces between words, you will have to change the way it shortens the string when it is measuring.

**EDIT**

To fix the text overlap on corners, I added a calculation for it:

```
    private static void DrawBrokenLine(PointF[] line, string text, Graphics g, Font font)
    {
        float lastOverlap = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index < line.Length - 1; index++)
        {
            float distance = distanceBetween(line[index], line[index + 1]);

            float angleOfLines = 180;
            if (index < line.Length - 2)
            {
                angleOfLines = angleBetweenLines(line[index], line[index + 1], line[index + 2]);
            }

            if (text.Length > 0)
            {
                SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString(text, font);
                float overlap = 0;
                if (angleOfLines < 180)
                {
                    if (angleOfLines <= 90)
                    {
                        overlap = (textSize.Height / 1.5f) / (
                            Convert.ToSingle(Math.Tan((angleOfLines / 2) * Math.PI / 180))
                            );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        overlap = Convert.ToSingle(
                            Math.Sin(angleOfLines * Math.PI / 180) * (textSize.Height / 1.5f));
                    }
                }

                for (int cIndex = text.Length; cIndex >= 0; cIndex--)
                {
                    textSize = g.MeasureString(text.Substring(0, cIndex).Trim(), font);

                    if (textSize.Width <= distance - overlap - lastOverlap)   //notice the subtraction of overlap
                    {
                        float rotation = angleBetween(line[index], line[index + 1]);

                        g.TranslateTransform(line[index].X, line[index].Y);
                        g.RotateTransform(rotation);

                        g.DrawString(text.Substring(0, cIndex).Trim(), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
                            new PointF(lastOverlap, -textSize.Height));

                        g.RotateTransform(-rotation);
                        g.TranslateTransform(-line[index].X, -line[index].Y);

                        text = text.Remove(0, cIndex);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                lastOverlap = overlap;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }

    private static float angleBetweenLines(PointF A, PointF B, PointF C)
    {
        float angle1 = 360 - angleBetween(A, B);
        float angle2 = 360 - angleBetween(B, C);

        if (angle1 < 0)
            angle1 += 360;
        if (angle2 < 0)
            angle2 += 360;

        float delta = 180 + angle1 - angle2;

        if (delta < 0)
            delta += 360;
        if (delta > 360)
            delta -= 360;

        return delta;
    }
```

[image]

There is a caveat with my example: if you notice, I divided text height by a special number. I had trouble with `MeasureString` not returning an accurate height for the text, so I attempted to correct for this manually.

Concerning drawing a string above the line (because of too many breaks), it depends on how you want to detect that situation (what constitutes too many, where should the text be placed, should it be at an angle?). Maybe if you can provide an example image of this situation you have in mind that would help clarify.

Comment: Thanks, it works:) I have almost done it myself, but there was an X-Y-offset that appeared because of bad matrix transformations:P (my bad). But your solutions works nice:) Could you check my edit, please?

Comment: @Nickon Updated my answer regarding text overlap.

Comment: Last thing:D What if there is a broken line that contains hundred of 2-3 pixel sublines? Is there any way to modify it? Or should I try any algorithm?:S

Comment: You could try using smaller fonts with MeasureString until it fit, but if they are 2-3 pixels you may not get the characters small enough. You could also try detecting when you have several of these small lines, capturing the distance variable over several iterations, then draw the text "above" the lines by noting where the highest point is, and drawing above that.

Comment: Yes, I've already corrected it, but the problem is, I don't know how to normalize the angle (there are some cases, the letters are rotated badly). For now I get the first and the last point of "overiterated" sublines. Then I tilt it according to the line between these two points. Works pretty good, but still there are SOME cases... :P